# How to get the :remote => true working to update a part of the page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In Rails 2, I used this kind of code to get a certain part of the page to update.

```
<div id="sidebar_div" class="span-3">
  <ul class="sidebar_list">
    <% for page in @section.pages %>
    <li><%= link_to_remote "#{page.name}", :update=>'show_page', :url => { :controller=>'pages',:action=>'show_page', :id=>page.id }, :html=>{} %></li>
    <hr/>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id='show_page' class='span-18 last vert_divider'>
  <%= render :partial => 'pages/show', :locals => { :page=>@page } %>
</div>
```

In the controller pages, I had a show_page method that just rendered the partial again.

In Rails 3, I DON'T KNOW HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS.  I want to use jQuery, which I already know how to code, but I don't know how to get it working in this way.  Should I create a js.erb file in my view?  I watched the http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript but I still don't know how to get it working to update one part of the page! Basically, I have this sidebar with links on it, and each time a user a clicks on one of them, the central part of the page should update - AJAX!  How do I do this? Do I still need this show_page method in the controller?

Comment: Please fix your code, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to an answer.
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/acfa800c83231c92
xD

Answer (score 2):

All `link_to_remote` helpers were removed from Rails 3. Instead you call it like this:

```
link_to "#{page_name}", :remote => true #ect
```

See [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) link for more information about changes to the URL helpers in Rails 3.